# Unexpected token ILLEGAL javascript error in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, webkit

I am getting a javascript (prototype.js) error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at this line of code:

```
newFriend = new friend(
    response[0].@items[0]._id, 
    response[0].@items[0]._nickName, 
    response[0].@items[0]._profilePicture, 
    response[0].@items[0]._tagLine, 
    response[0].@items[0]._isInvite, 
    response[0].@items[0]._confirm
);
```

the response object looks like this:

```
[{
  "@type": "[Lcom.photoviewer.common.model.ThinUser;",
  "@items": [{
    "_id": "000.060318.05022007.00263.0067ur",
    "_nickName": "siraj",
    "_country": null,
    "_currentStorageLimit": 5000000000,
    "_currentStorage": 0,
    "_currentFileCount": 0,
    "_profilePicture": null,
    "_tagLine": null,
    "_membershipLevel": 0,
    "_isRejected": false,
    "_isInvite": false,
    "_confirm": false,
    "_verifiedOn": 1170716666000
  }]
}]
```

This is only happening in the Google Chrome browser and possibly other webkit browsers. It works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
newFriend = new friend(
    response[0]["@items"][0]._id, 
    response[0]["@items"][0]._nickName, 
    response[0]["@items"][0]._profilePicture, 
    response[0]["@items"][0]._tagLine, 
    response[0]["@items"][0]._isInvite, 
    response[0]["@items"][0]._confirm
);
```

I'm pretty sure `@` is giving you a problem.

For weird characters it's always safer to use the `["@items"]` notation instead of the (dot) notation `.@items`.

Answer (score 0):

Property names containing `@` and dot notation are incompatible in Chrome. Use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/) instead (you already do when you construct the object).

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised it works anywhere at all! `@` is very definitely not allowed in a JS identifier (according to ECMA-262-3 et al).